# data don't get from local storage (react)

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

I'm just trying to set some contact data in local storage and render on DOM but after reloading the page there is no contact data in localStorage to render in DOM!
I tried in other browsers but the result is equal.

**here is my code:**

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import ContactForm from "./ContactForm";
import ContactList from "./ContactList";

const ContactApp = () => {
  const [contacts, setContacts] = useState([]);

  const addContactHandler = (formValues) => {
    if (!formValues.name || !formValues.email) {
      toast.error("Name and email are required");
      return;
    }
    setContacts([...contacts, { ...formValues, id: Date.now() }]);
  };

  const deleteContactHandler = (id) => {
    setContacts(contacts.filter((contact) => contact.id !== id));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const savedContacts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("contacts"));
    if (savedContacts) setContacts(savedContacts);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("contacts", JSON.stringify(contacts));
  }, [contacts]);

  return (
    <div className="contact-app">
      <nav>
        <h1>Contact Manager</h1>
      </nav>
      <ContactForm onClick={addContactHandler} />
      <ContactList onDelete={deleteContactHandler} contacts={contacts} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default ContactApp;
```

Comment: Can you check with the development console if it is a problem reading the data or writing it?

Comment: Yeah. I agree with @CerebralFart. Please check and let us know so we can debug efficiently

Comment: You are calling the `useEffect` that sets the item in local storage when the contact changes. But when you are again retrieving the data when the component loads, you are setting the `contacts` so which causes the `localStorage.setItem()` effect everytime you try to get the value and store it.

Comment: @CerebralFart there is no error nor warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the explanation:

When you are calling the function to get the data from `localstorage`, you are also setting the contacts variable to the new data.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const savedContacts = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("contacts"));
    if (savedContacts) setContacts(savedContacts); // Here you are changing the value of 'contacts'
}, []);
```

**BUT**, You are also calling the `localStorage.setItem` method whenever the value of the contacts variable changes.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("contacts", JSON.stringify(contacts));
}, [contacts]); // Here you are calling it when the contacts change.
```

So basically, when the component loads in the first useEffect. You are checking to see if contacts exist and setting the contacts variable to the existing contacts.

But you are also setting the value of the `localStorage` **WHENEVER** the value of the `contacts` variable changes.

its like: 
*Fetching Data the first time it loads and storing it* --> *because you have stored the data and the value of `contacts` has changed, it again sets the value of the contacts* ----> *which can lead to storing `undefined` or `[]` values if the contacts don't already have some default value.*

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem. When you use the strict   <React.StrictMode>  </React.StrictMode> it renders 2 times, that caused the problem, try comment strict mode and give it another try. Hope this fix it for you to. Cheers!